# Are Magic: the Gathering Conspiracy cards colorless?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What is the color of the following Magic conspiracy cards:

- Advantageous Proclamation
- Backup Plan
- Brago's Favor
- Double Stroke
- Immediate Action
- Iterative Analysis
- Muzzio's Preparations
- Power Play
- Secret Summoning
- Secrets of Paradise
- Sentinel Dispatch
- Unexpected Potential
- Worldknit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conspiracy cards (cards with the Conspiracy type) are colorless. They are not permanents, they cannot be played in decks, they only exist in the command zone*, and they never interact with cards, abilities, or effects that care about color.

Rule [105.2](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Colors_(rules)) says

> An object is the color or colors of the mana symbols in its mana cost, regardless of the color of its frame. An object's color or colors may also be defined by a color indicator or a characteristic-defining ability.

and rule [202.2b](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Mana#Mana_Cost_and_Color) says

> Objects with no colored mana symbols in their mana costs are colorless.

Conspiracy cards do not have mana costs (in particular, no colored mana symbols), color indicators, or characteristic-defining abilities, so they do not have any color; they are colorless.

---

* This was clarified in the Magic 2015 update:

> 313.3. Conspiracy cards remain in the command zone throughout the game. They’re not permanents. 
>   They can’t be cast or included in a deck. If a conspiracy card would leave the command zone, it 
>   remains in the command zone.

Comment: I don't know about only existing in the Command Zone. You could open a Conspiracy pack with a Booster Tutor to put it into your hand, where it could interact with any number of cards that interact with the hand.

Comment: Booster Tutor is Unhinged, and like many cards in that set it does not work in the MTG rules. By that same argument, you could put a rules card in your hand, but we don't have rules about that either.

Comment: It seems very picky to say that you're considering Conspiracies, a card legal in a tiny sliver of Magic games, but won't also consider an Unhinged card, which is also legal in a tiny sliver of Magic games. Kind of a double standard. You're talking about two of the only "draft-only" sets in existence. It doesn't make sense to start drawing arbitrary lines.

Comment: @corsiKa The comprehensive rules include rules for conspiracy cards and Conspiracy Draft, so even if there are some funky rules quirks out there, Wizards clearly made an effort to make them fit into the rules framework. They've also made it pretty clear that Un- cards aren't really covered by the comp rules. That seems like a fairly good reason to make a distinction between Conspiracy and Unhinged.

Comment: @corsika Conspiracy cards work within the rules. Unhinged cards do not. What part of that line is arbitrary?

Comment: @corsiKa If you think Un cards have *any* place whatsoever in valid MTG play, I'd like to play against you with my R&D's Secret Lair/Ashnod's Coupon deck, preferably in an expensive bar.

Comment: I think that this answer is incorrect. Rule 105.2c: **A colorless object has no color.** So technically, Conspiracy cards are colorless.

Comment: Unless it says "all objects with no color are colorless", I don't think I need to change anything

Comment: Ok fine. Here is another one. 202.2b **Objects with no colored mana symbols in their mana costs are colorless**

Comment: When you are done with that one, explain [this](http://forums.mtgvault.com/showthread.php?t=1975), [this](http://tappedout.net/mtg-questions/are-basic-lands-considered-colored-permanents/), and [this](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/261910-basic-land-color-questions). Those are the top three Google results for *"What color are basic lands"* without quotes.

Comment: 202.2b seems like a pretty strong case for calling them colorless, so I have changed my answer.

Comment: @murgatroid99 For what it's worth, rule 105 itself also supports this, albeit not explicitly: "An object can be one or more of the five colors, or it can be no color at all." I think that, combined with the list below (monocolored, multicolored, colorless) at least implies that those are the only possibilities for any object.

Answer (score 2):

None of the Conspiracy cards have any mana costs, color indicators, or characteristic-defining abilities relating to color.  Thus, they are all colorless.

Comment: I think you should reference rule **202.2b** *Objects with no colored mana symbols in their mana costs are colorless* or rule **105.2c** *A colorless object has no color* or both.